# Setting up a LLC in Wyoming as a non-resident to invest in stocks

Tags: taxes, capital-gains-tax, irs, dividends, limited-liability-company

I would like to open a LLC in the US in order to have access to some online brokers, like Interactive Brokers and Robinhood. I understand I will need to file an annual report with the state (Wyoming for example) and pay $52 fee. However the tax reporting is really confusing.

From what I understand I don't have to pay capital gains tax, because I will be paying it in my home country. For dividends the brokers withhold 30% tax, so I don't have to do anything there either. But:

1. Do I have to file a yearly tax return?
2. Do I have to file quarterly estimated tax?

If yes, is that something people generally do themselves, or is it almost required to pay a professional to do it?

I'm a non-resident alien, I don't plan travelling to the US.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**[LLCs still pay taxes](https://finance.zacks.com/capital-gains-offsets-llc-operating-losses-7938.html#:%7E:text=The%20LLC%20pays%20taxes%20on,at%20their%20individual%20tax%20rates.)**

**[Non-resident aliens also pay taxes to the US](https://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/06/nonusresidenttax.asp)**

There is no getting around paying taxes in the U.S. if you transact here.  Dividends and stock buying/selling are generally very public activities.  There will be public records of the publicly traded companies sending you a check or depositing into your account.  Even if you manage to evade paying taxes the first time, the IRS can seize future earnings, so any tax dodge will be sort-lived.